# Event.target is not precise on key events, but works perfect with click events, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We bind listener to `contenteditable` node - why does `event.target` deliver the wrong parent on key(up, press or down) events, but gets the precise parent on click events when ?

HTML:

```
<div class="wysiwyg_editor" contenteditable="true">
  <h2>Hello There</h2>
  <p>If you click on LI, nodeName will be 'LI', but if you use keys to move around, nodeName will be 'DIV', strange!</p>
  <p><b>Why :() ?</b></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Heros are forever</li>
    <li><b>Wars</b> are weapons of dirty <b>politicians</b></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
let div = document.querySelector(".wysiwyg_editor");

let f = function(event) {
            console.log(`Event Type: ${event.type} Target: ${event.target.nodeName}`);
        }

div.addEventListener('click',f);
div.addEventListener('keyup',f);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

[Have a look on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmVRZL)

(here is [jquery version](https://codepen.io/oddimportance/pen/QZRaod) (before question update))

To reproduce problem in codepen, click on some text and edit it - and look on console on click and keyup events.

Comment: yes - I see - hm very strange - so question is - how to get direct target element of keyup event (and why it works without problems for  'click' event) - good question

Comment: Here is version without jquery: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmVRZL - so it is not jquery bug, but browser bug

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - convinced! Cheers for the proof!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the targeting of key presses only applies to input tags and tags with contenteditable attributes. Since your contenteditable is only on the wrapping div, the target will always refer to it. Typing in the children will bubble up to the contenteditable parent. To get the result you are looking for, I've placed the contenteditable on the children:

```js
$('.wysiwyg_editor').bind('click keyup',
  function(event) {
    console.log(`Event Type: ${event.type} Target: ${event.target.nodeName}`);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wysiwyg_editor">
  <h2>Hello There</h2>
  <p class="wysiwyg_editor" contenteditable="true">If you click on LI, nodeName will be 'LI', but if you use keys to move around, nodeName will be 'DIV', strange!</p>
  <p><b>Why :() ?</b></p>
  <ul>
    <li class="wysiwyg_editor" contenteditable="true">Heros are forever</li>
    <li class="wysiwyg_editor" contenteditable="true"><b>Wars</b> are weapons of dirty <b>politicians</b></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Alright, I got the point. +1 for figuring out the leak. However, unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. Would it be considerably appropriate to flag this a jQuery Bug?!

Comment: @Odd - i think it is not jQuery bug but browser event system bug

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Save last mouse event and read it on key event to get target:

```
let div = document.querySelector(".wysiwyg_editor");
let lastClickEvent = null;
let f = function(event) 
{
      let e = event
      if(event instanceof MouseEvent) {
        lastClickEvent=event;
      } else {
        e = lastClickEvent ? lastClickEvent : event;
      }

      console.log(`Event Type: ${event.type} Target: ${e.target.nodeName}`);
}

div.addEventListener('click',f);
div.addEventListener('keyup',f);
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePwrvd

I report this bug to firefox [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1503532) - I wonder what will they replay

Comment: Unfortunately, did not have the expected results on tests

Comment: @Odd - describe tests

Comment: I clicked on "Why :() ?", colsole.log - "B", which is correct. I then press the upper arrow and expected console.log to be "P", but it was "B" again.

Comment: @Odd In above example code I give idea (I assume that user always first click before start type-ing). But if you want to handle arrows, you should detect this keys and use some tree-algorithm to find element above/below current node and put it to variable `lastNode` and use that. Of course - this is only some workarount to this bug - the real solution will be fix this bug by browsers.

Comment: Kamil Kiełczewski - sounds reasonable, I'll give a go. Await Bugzilla's response curiously, cheers.

Comment: @Odd - they replay - this bug is duplicate - and probably they don't fix it fast (it has 4 years)

Comment: Kamil Kiełczewski - a pity, but sincerely appreciate your enthusiasm. cheers!